# "Cases" can not find "EllipticPi" inside expression

Tags: bugs, pattern-matching

Why the following code does not find any of `EllipticPi` while at the same time it finds all `EllipticE` or `EllipticF`?

```
$Version
expr = (2 + EllipticF[x1, 5] + EllipticE[x1, 5] + 
    EllipticPi[x1, 5, 7])/(3 + EllipticF[3, x2] + EllipticE[3, x2] + 
    EllipticPi[3, x2, 7])
Cases[expr, EllipticE[_, _], All]
Cases[expr, EllipticF[_, _], All]
Cases[expr, EllipticPi[_, _, _], All]

(* "13.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)" *)

(* (2 + EllipticE[x1, 5] + EllipticF[x1, 5] + EllipticPi[x1, 5, 7])/(3 + 
 EllipticE[3, x2] + EllipticF[3, x2] + EllipticPi[3, x2, 7]) *)

(* {EllipticE[3, x2], EllipticE[x1, 5]} *)

(* {EllipticF[3, x2], EllipticF[x1, 5]} *)

(* {} *)
```

Comment: `Cases[expr, EllipticPi[a_, b_, c_], All]`

Comment: `Cases[expr, EllipticPi[_, _, __], All]` (With two"_" in the third slots works for some reason.

Comment: @cvgmt: But that does not answer the question. It is a workaround.

Comment: That also does not answer the question :-)

Comment: `Cases[expr, EllipticPi[_, ___], All]` also work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `HoldPattern` :

```
Cases[expr, HoldPattern[EllipticPi[_, _, _]], All]
```

`EllipticPi[_, _, _]` is getting evaluated without it.

```
InputForm[EllipticPi[_, _, _]]
```

`Piecewise[{{(EllipticE[_, _] - (_*Cos[_]*Sin[_])/Sqrt[1 - _*Sin[_]^2])/(1 - _), -Pi < Arg[1 - _] < Pi && _ != 1},  {(Log[Sec[_]*(1 + Sin[_])] + Sec[_]*Tan[_])/2, _ == 1 && (-1/2*Pi < Re[_] < Pi/2 || (Re[_] == -1/2*Pi && Im[_] > 0) ||  (Re[_] == Pi/2 && Im[_] < 0))}, {(EllipticE[_, _] - (_*Cos[_]*Sin[_])/Sqrt[1 - _*Sin[_]^2])/(1 - _),  Im[_] == 0 && Re[_] > 1 && (-1/2*Pi < Re[_] < Pi/2 || (Re[_] == -1/2*Pi && Im[_] > 0) ||  (Re[_] == Pi/2 && Im[_] < 0)) && Arg[-1 + _*Sin[_]^2] != 0}}, ComplexInfinity]`

Comment: Ahhh... this is the cause. But why? I think it is a bug. Why `EllipticPi[_, _, _]` should be weirdly evaluated while `EllipticPi[_, _, __]` not?

Comment: Something in the definition of `EllipticPi` must cause it to treat `EllipticPi[Blank[], Blank[], Blank[]]` different than `EllipticPi[Blank[], Blank[], BlankSequence[]]`  Maybe it has to do with it being able to accept either two or three parameters...

Comment: I figured out what it is. When all three arguments are the same there is probably some simplification in computation of `EllipticPi`. Once it sees three same arguments it tries to evaluate in this simplified version but do not check what they are before evaluation. `EllipticPi[blah, blah, blah]` is also evaluated.

Comment: Ahh! ok,  in fact, I think it is when the first and third are equal such as: `EllipticPi[a, b, a]`

Comment: You are even more precise! :-)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_third_kind   
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjImh.png

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

expr = (2 + EllipticF[x1, 5] + EllipticE[x1, 5] + EllipticPi[x1, 5, 7])/(3 + 
     EllipticF[3, x2] + EllipticE[3, x2] + EllipticPi[3, x2, 7]);
```

I recommend that you select `Cases` by their heads

```
Cases[expr, #, All] & /@
 {_EllipticE, _EllipticF, _EllipticPi}

(* {{EllipticE[3, x2], EllipticE[x1, 5]}, {EllipticF[3, x2], 
  EllipticF[x1, 5]}, {EllipticPi[3, x2, 7], EllipticPi[x1, 5, 7]}} *)
```

Comment: But that does not answer the question. It is a workaround.

Comment: And what if I want to find only `EllipticE[3, x2]` where the  first argument is `3`? Using heads finds all.

Comment: The question asked to find all, so I offer an option for doing that in a more straightforward fashion. I did not suggest that using the `Head` would be a general solution for other cases.

Comment: The question is not to find "all" but "all that match the pattern".